# How can I delete a favicon on a non self hosted site using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://files.writeas.org/favicon.ico" />
```

Is the code in the site, I can't change this, I can only change the CSS or inject my own Javascript, thus how would I grab this part of the HTML code using Javascript and comment it out / override it thus deleting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can't delete it you might change it with the following code 
(note: a delete might not be enough as many bowsers default to /favicon.ico)

```js
//const ico_url = document.location.origin + '/favicon.ico'
const ico_url = 'https://api.adorable.io/avatar/256/your_icon.png'
let head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
console.dir(head)
var link;
let links = head.getElementsByTagName('link')
for(let i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
   if (links[i].rel == 'icon' || links[i].rel == 'shortcut icon') {
      link = links[i]
      console.log('old-icon: '+link.href)
      link.href = ico_url
      console.log('new-icon: '+link.href)
 
   }

}

if (typeof(link) == 'undefined') {
 console.log('creating favicon link !')
 link = document.createElement('link')
 link.setAttribute('rel','icon')
 link.setAttribute('type','image/png')
 link.setAttribute('href',ico_url) // new favicon ...
 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link)
}
console.log(link.href)
```

Comment: This looks like it should work. I get no errors on the site when I add the code to it obviously with the changed favicon URL in place. I don't get any errors in the console, only the word `undefined`

Comment: the undefined  is because this page has no "link" w. a rel = "icon"
however is your site doesn't have a link either then you have to create it ...

let me update my code for this :)

Comment: try with the new code now, and let me know how it works for you ?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/d569b96bee7915d040aedb9f5631d4ec I now get this in the console and the favicon still remains

Comment: can you give us the url of the page you'd like to change the favicon ? 
somehow the have a tag that set their favicon or something prevent you to set it

you might want to check the <head> ...
with a ``console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0])``

Comment: this is because the have <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://files.writeas.org/favicon.ico"> instead of "icon", I'll fixe the code again then

Comment: I tried this new code, it still does not work this time with no errors or anything in the console.

Comment: without having hands on your setup, it is hard to guess what is the solution, can you delay the execution of your script, making sure you are the last one to overwrite the favicon ... and if you are "sandboxed" in an iframe or so then I believe you can't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to replace the head tag ...

```js
let ico_url = 'https://api.adorable.io/avatar/256/head_icon.png'
 var head = document.createElement("head");
 link = document.createElement('link')
 link.setAttribute('rel','icon')
 link.setAttribute('type','image/png')
 link.setAttribute('href',ico_url) // new favicon ...
 head.appendChild(link)

 const html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]
 html.appendChild(head)
 html.replaceChild(head,document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0])
console.dir(head)
```

Comment: Still does not work, at this point I give up, I still marked the answer as correct above as it should work really, but it must be the browser or server defaulting it or something as mentioned.